# Examples of designs that keep a title or heading in view

Tags: design-patterns, scrolling

I'm looking for examples of designs where there is special logic that prevents a title, heading, or landmark from being moved out of view, so that the user doesn't lose their context.

Examples:

- Excel's "Freeze top row"
- iOS UITableView (notice the "A" subheading floats)

[image]

What are some other examples? I'm especially interested in examples that handle more complex situations than simple tables. For example, a graphical app where the user can scroll in a more freeform way, or where multiple headers can be floating at once.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [biathlontime](http://biathlontime.com/2010-2011/world-cup/men/) — selected table rows stick to the top of the window.

Answer (score 0):

http://corp.ign.com/ has a nice "sticky" top menu.

Also, check out the [floating sidebar on uxmag](http://uxmag.com/strategy/etrades-digital-customer-experience).

Answer (score 0):

**Gmail Application for Android**

The Gmail application for Android has these type of headers when viewing an email. The header changes as you scroll down based on what actions you can do with the message you are viewing (e.g. reply, forward, star).

Answer (score 0):

Themed tables in **Drupal 7 and 6**, e.g. the list of modules page.

[image]

Internally, this is thanks to the [theme_table](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--theme.inc/function/theme_table/7) function which has a boolean option `$sticky`, so any page, even custom user-created pages, can easily use this feature as well, regardless of the active theme.

Comment: The Apple website also had a nice accordion somewhere with sticky headers and that automatically opens the next item if you scroll past the contents of the active accordion item, but I can't seem to find that page anymore. Anyone else remembers seeing that UI element ?